# Divide a string at first space

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

For a chat-bot, if someone says "!say " it will recite what you say after the space. Simple.

Example input:

```
!say this is a test
```

Desired output:

```
this is a test
```

The string can be represented as `s` for sake of argument. `s.Split(' ')` yields an array.

`s.Split(' ')[1]` is just the first word after the space, any ideas on completely dividing and getting *all* words after the first space?

I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
s.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i > s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == "!say")
    {
        s[i] = "";
    }
}
```

The input being:

```
!say this is a test
```

The output:

```
!say
```

Which is obviously not what I wanted :p

(I know there are several answers to this question, but none written in C# from where I searched.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the overload of s.Split that has a "maximum" parameter.

It's this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

Looks like:

```
var s = "!say this is a test";
var commands = s.Split (' ', 2);

var command = commands[0];  // !say
var text = commands[1];     // this is a test
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `s` in `(s, 2)` be a char?

Comment: There's no overload of Split taking (char, int). You probably meant `s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2)`

Comment: @StefanMonov it's work!! you're right please explain why it work by adding `new[] { ' ' }`

Answer (score 8):

You can use string.Substring method for that:

```
s.Substring(s.IndexOf(' '))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = "say this is a test";
return value.Substring(value.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me. I added the **new []** and it works

```
var s = "!say this is a test";
var commands = s.Split (new [] {' '}, 2);

var command = commands[0];  // !say
var text = commands[1];     // this is a test
```